# What's the correct way to read a text file in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to make a program in C++ that must read and write text files line by line with an specific format, but the problem is that in my PC I work in Windows, and in College they have Linux and I am having problems because of line endings are different in these OS.

I am new to C++ and don't know could I make my program able read the files no matter if they were written in Linux or Windows. Can anybody give me some hints? thanks!

The input is like this:

```
James White 34 45.5 10 black
Miguel Chavez 29 48.7 9 red
David McGuire 31 45.8 10 blue
```

Each line being a record of a struct of 6 variables.

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: I am using the fstream's getline() function

Comment: it is \r\n so a delimiter if \n should read a line regardless of Linux or Windows http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Comment: thanks. You suggest me to use '\n' as the third parameter of getline (delimiter) and it will work? What about the '\r'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can already read the files, just check for all of the newline characters like `"\n"` and `"\r"`. I'm pretty sure that linux uses `"\r\n"` as the newline character.

You can read this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

and here is a list of all the ascii codes including the newline characters:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Edit: Linux uses `"\n"`, Windows uses `"\r\n"`, Mac uses `"\r"`. Thanks to Seth Carnegie

Comment: Linux uses `\n`, windows uses `\r\n`, Mac uses `\r`

Comment: I have read about the '\r\n' in Windows and '\n' in Linux. Mac I don't know. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SethCarnegie: *older* Mac systems used `'\r'`, but Mac OS X (being certified Unix) uses `'\n'`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: nothing in windows requires `\r\n` except `notepad.exe`.  Don't encourage people to add them in their programs.

Comment: @AndréCaron I never did encourage anyone to use `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `std::getline` overload without the last (i.e. delimiter) parameter should take care of the end-of-line conversions automatically:

```
std::ifstream in("TheFile.txt");
std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    // Do something with 'line'.
}
```

Comment: No, at least on Linux it doesn't strip the "\r" from "\r\n".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to strip string of an extra "\r":

```
std::ifstream in("TheFile.txt");
std::string line;

std::getline(input, line));
if (line[line.size() - 1] == '\r')
    line.resize(line.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the result will be CR LF, I would add something like the following to consume the extras if they exist. So once your have read you record call this before trying to read the next.

```
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try it too next monday at the College

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of values you are going to read for each record you could simply use the ">>" method. For example:

```
fstream f("input.txt" std::ios::in);
string tempStr;
double tempVal;

for (number of records) {
    // read the first name
    f >> tempStr;
    // read the last name
    f >> tempStr;
    // read the number
    f >> tempVal;
    // and so on.
}
```

Shouldn't that suffice ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will give you the answer in stages. Please go trough in order to understand the code.

**Stage 1: Design our program:**
Our program based on the requirements should...:

- ...include a definition of a data type that would hold the data. i.e. our
  structure of 6 variables.
- ...provide user interaction i.e. the user should be able to
  provide the program, the file name and its location.
- ...be able to
  open the chosen file.
- ...be able to read the file data and
  write/save them into our structure.
- ...be able to close the file
  after the data is read.
- ...be able to print out of the saved data.

Usually you should split your code into functions representing the above.

**Stage 2: Create an array of the chosen structure to hold the data**

```
...
#define MAX 10
...
strPersonData sTextData[MAX];
...
```

**Stage 3: Enable user to give in both the file location and its name:**

```
.......
string sFileName;
cout << "Enter a file name: ";
getline(cin,sFileName);
ifstream inFile(sFileName.c_str(),ios::in);
.....
```

**->Note 1 for stage 3.** The accepted format provided then by the user should be:

> `c:\\SomeFolder\\someTextFile.txt`

We use two \ backslashes instead of one \, because we wish it to be treated as literal backslash.

**->Note 2 for stage 3.** We use ifstream i.e. input file stream because we want to read data from file. This
is expecting the file name as c-type string instead of a c++ string. For this reason we use:

```
..sFileName.c_str()..
```

**Stage 4: Read all data of the chosen file:**

```
...
    while (!inFile.eof())   { //we loop while there is still data in the file to read
...
    }
...
```

So finally the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAX 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sFileName;

    struct strPersonData    {
        char c1stName[25];
        char c2ndName[30];
        int iAge;
        double dSomeData1;      //i had no idea what the next 2 numbers represent in your code :D
        int iSomeDate2;
        char cColor[20];        //i dont remember the lenghts of the different colors.. :D
        };

    strPersonData sTextData[MAX];

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    getline(cin,sFileName);
    ifstream inFile(sFileName.c_str(),ios::in);

    int i=0;
    while (!inFile.eof())   { //loop while there is still data in the file

       inFile >>sTextData[i].c1stName>>sTextData[i].c2ndName>>sTextData[i].iAge
            >>sTextData[i].dSomeData1>>sTextData[i].iSomeDate2>>sTextData[i].cColor;

        ++i;
    }
    inFile.close();

    cout << "Reading the file finished. See it yourself: \n"<< endl;
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        cout<<sTextData[j].c1stName<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].c2ndName
            <<"\t"<<sTextData[j].iAge<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].dSomeData1
            <<"\t"<<sTextData[j].iSomeDate2<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].cColor<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am going to give you some exercises now :D :D

**1) In the last loop:**

```
for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
    cout<<sTextData[j].c1stName<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].c2ndName
        <<"\t"<<sTextData[j].iAge<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].dSomeData1
        <<"\t"<<sTextData[j].iSomeDate2<<"\t"<<sTextData[j].cColor<<endl;}
```

Why do I use variable i instead of lets say MAX???

**2) Could u change the program based on stage 1 on sth like:**

```
int main(){

function1()
function2()
...
functionX()

...return 0;
}
```

I hope i helped...